# How to use Compose's createRippleModifierNode

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/touch-input/user-interactions/migrate-indication-ripple#globally-change-ripples

I noticed Google updated their docs for how to set a global on ripple theme but they don't mention or show how you are suppose to use `createRippleModifierNode`. How are you suppose to use this function and apply it globally to your app?

I tried just putting it my root view but nothing changed.

Comment: This is not for setting a ripple effect for your app, it is intended to be used for [custom design systems](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/designsystems/custom): "*This function allows for design system libraries to create higher order wrapper implementation, that query their theme values and then delegate the ripple implementation to the node created by this function.*". -- Is this really what you are looking for? The wording of your question suggests otherwise.